# Constant name is expected. Error

Tags: error, magento-2.0, cli

I am receiving this error:

> Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Constant name is expected.

While running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` in command line.

i got this http://awesomescreenshot.com/0535zi4648 error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think some problem in your **etc** folder.
 check all **xml** files. Constant name should be in `CAPITAL` letters. any of your constant remain in small letters. check it and correct it. Hope this will solve your Problem.

Answer (score 31):

In order to help you debug what's going on, I would suggest to **temporary** edit the file

`vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php`

From this...

```
public function evaluate(array $data) {
    if(!isset($data['value']) || !defined($data['value'])) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Constant name is expected.');
    }
    return constant($data['value']);
}
```

To this...

```
public function evaluate(array $data) {
    if(!isset($data['value']) || !defined($data['value'])) {
        print_r($data);exit;                                                    // <<<<<<<<<<<<
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Constant name is expected.');
    }
    return constant($data['value']);
}
```

Thereby you will be notified of which class / constant is causing you the error :

[image]

Hope it could help someone else ;-)
See ya

Comment: Hello! I just got Array ( [name] => dateFormat [value] => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT ), what can I do next?

Comment: I think your case may be particular because \IntlDateFormatter isn't part of Magento but more of a PHP extension. Without context I would say that "intl" is not installed but required by Magento : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html.

Answer (score 18):

##### Edit, extra information:

As explained below, please investigate **folder names/case** for your files, also make sure the class defined matches your file path.
Incorrect folder case/names means the CONSTANT cannot be resolved based on the class where it is defined, in which case the error message might not initially be useful.  See the other answers on which core file to override to get more information on the file causing the issue.

#### Original:

In the case when your extension is in `app/code` folder, you will get this error if your folder name is different than module name after Magento_ in module.xml

For example:
If your module name is **Magento_MyGreatModule** your folder name must be **MyGreatModule**.

Comment: thank you ! another great example of misleading error msg ...

Comment: This answer worked for me as well.

Comment: Thank you! Bumped into this one after I renamed my module.

Comment: Wow. I guess this answer saved me hours frustration.

Comment: @medmek, I don't think the error is misleading, sure when the 3rd party module doesn't have the correct folder structure as defined in their classes, this is troublesome to find and fix.   Overriding the `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php` file and outputting the `$data`, and then using this answer in conjunction with the result it is clear why this error message is useless (but not misleading).  They *should have given more output* for the error by default though.

Comment: @CvRChameleon Indeed, thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Like already stated in the previous answers, this is most likely because some error in one of your configuration files. For instance, this error is triggered when you do the following without having a class that declares the constant (notice the `::CODE` declaration):

```
<!-- etc/di.xml -->
<virtualType name="ExamplePaymentGatewayConfig" type="Magento\Payment\Gateway\Config\Config">
  <arguments>
    <argument name="methodCode" xsi:type="const">\Company\Example\Model\Ui\ConfigProvider::CODE</argument>
  </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing module's namespace without changing the actual directory name caused the issue on my end.

Comment: +1 Look for "CamelCase" in vendor name or module name. It should match what is specified in registration.php

Answer (score 0):

In my case the const CODE has wrong name and temporary modify the file

> `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php`

Is helped me to find the name of the actual module.

Answer (score 0):

check if you did  "composer install"