# "Constant name is expected" when installing a module

Tags: magento2, composer, third-party-module, setup-upgrade

I'm trying to install a third party module via composer with very low support, so I have to debug it myself.

### The problem

I'm encountering an error "Constant name is expected" when I try to `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.
I've searched around and found [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122905/constant-name-is-expected-error), which led me to modify some magento code and display more details about the error :

```php
Array
(
    [name] => code
    [value] => CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider::CODE
)
```

This is the class under `{root_vendor_dir}/creditagricole/etransactions/Model/Ui`

```php
//class EtepcbConfigProvider
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Ui;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
// use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
// use Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Source;
use \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Gateway\Http\Client\ClientMock;
use CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfig;

/**
 * Class ConfigProvider
 */
final class EtepcbConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    const CODE = 'etep_cb';
    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    'cards' => $this->getCards()
                ]
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getCards(){...}
}
```

### What I've tried so far

I've looked around where that constant is called and found several references in the module's etc folder :

`<argument name="code" xsi:type="const">\CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider::CODE</argument>`

I've searched for the same sort of code in magento core files and found that there were no first `\` like in this module, so I've tried removing it, but nothing changed.

The class throwing the error is :

```php
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\InterpreterInterface;

/**
 * Interpreter that returns value of a constant by its name
 */
class Constant implements InterpreterInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function evaluate(array $data) {
        if(!isset($data['value']) || !defined($data['value'])) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Constant name is expected.');
        }
        return constant($data['value']);
    }
}
```

I've tested both the isset and defined function separately and got these results:

```php
 print_r($data);
 // Array ( [name] => code [value] => \CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider::CODE )

 print_r(isset($data['value']));
// 1

 print_r(defined($data['value']));
// <nothing>
```

Finally, I've tried using `defined` with the constant name directly (with and without the first `\`) and got:

```php
print_r(defined(\CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider::CODE));
// Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php:24 Stack trace: #0

print_r(defined(CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider::CODE));
//Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php:24 Stack trace: #0

//using string (with and without \)
print_r(defined("\CreditAgricole\Etransactions\Model\Ui\EtepcbConfigProvider::CODE"));
//Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Constant name is expected. in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Argument/Interpreter/Constant.php:26
```

#### Dirty temporary fix ?

The last thing I've tried is moving the code base into app/code and renaming the top folders accordingly and SOMEHOW, this seems to fix the error. However the frontend content isn't working and I don't feel confident about this solution, as this module was meant to be installed with composer.
Do modules installed in `vendor` and `app/code` work differently or are they interchangeable ?

That's where I'm at today. I have no idea what's wrong with this module, this is the first time I see this error appear, just after having installed it. I would very much like to install it "normally".

### EDIT

I should have mentioned that this error appears for every `bin/magento` command

Comment: @ the author, have you ever found a solution for this?

I have Magento 2.3.5 installation that also experience this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands :

1. rm -rf generated/
2. sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
   then run di compile command :

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thanks, but I keep getting the same error

Comment: I should have mentioned that this error appears for every `bin/magento` command